# How to show issues in my repositories on GitHub

Tags: git, github, repository, issue-tracking

Up until a month ago, GitHub had an **Issues** view that allowed one to view open issues and pull requests in their own repositories. This was useful for seeing what was needed to be addressed across a lot of OSS projects.

**They recently released an update that (in my opinion) is a lot less useful**, as it only shows issues that one has either created, been assigned, or been mentioned in.

[image]

**This basically excludes all issues that have been created by others in my repositories.**

Is there an easy way in this new system to view all outstanding issues in my repositories (and better, in repositories in my organizations too)? At this point, the only solutions are either digging through e-mail or looking at repositories one by one, both of which are pretty unpalatable.

*I understand this isn't a programming question per se, but it's much more likely to be answered here than anywhere else.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Seems like the new way to do this is not obvious, but involves entering the following in the filter area:

```
is:open user:fooUser user:BarOrganization
```

This displays all open issues and pull requests under both the `fooUser` and `BarOrganization`  accounts.

(The default of `is:open is:issue` hides pull requests.)

Answer (score 0):

In the "Filter" area, if you clear out all the text and hit ENTER you will see what you want.

It is not very intuitive. But **GUI** and **slick** was what they apparently wanted instead.

Comment: If you're talking about the `is: open is:issue` area, I don't think that works. That just displays no results.

Comment: If anything, seems like `is:open user:mizzao user:SomeOrganization` is what I'm looking for. Shows both PRs and issues for both groups.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way in this new system to view all outstanding issues in my repositories

8 years later, you could consider the [GitHub CLI k](https://ttps://github.com/cli/cli), with its new ([2.7.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.7.0)) [`gh status` command](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/5369)

> Adds a new top level command, `gh status`: shows information about your work on GitHub across all the repositories to which you are subscribed.
>
> The information shown:
>
> - Assigned issues
> - Assigned PRs
> - Review Requests
> - Mentions
> - Repository Activity (new issues, comments, new PRs)
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/98482/160444808-91ee0fa4-fb5c-4349-99a2-6b7fd0bd2329.png]